# Unable to install Broadcomm drivers in Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, wireless-networking, drivers

I am having this weird problem on a new Ubuntu Installation on my laptop. Previously after installing ubuntu 12.04 on my laptop my wireless drivers got installed using the additional drivers option.   On this instance however, the STA driver installation failed citing `Sorry! Installation of this driver failed. Please have a look at jockey.log`.

Details :

- Ubuntu 12.04.3
- Dell Inspiron 1464
- Wireless Card BCM4312 LP-PHY. ( have forgotten how to check, but i remember the model)

I have tried google and the results didn't help, or may be I was unable to follow to the point.

Comment: Please insert the contents of jockey.log into your question, as it stands, there is very little info to go on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the problem by downloading the [`bcmwl-kernel-source`](http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/raring/restricted/base/bcmwl-kernel-source) deb package.

Don't know what the problem was though.

Answer (score 0):

Your model should be supported by the open source b43 driver. To activate it, [follow these steps](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43_-_Internet_access):

> To install b43-fwcutter issue the following commands in a terminal
>   (under the desktop menu Applications > Accessories > Terminal) and
>   follow the prompts:
>
> ```
> sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install b43-fwcutter
> ```
>
> Under the desktop menu System > Administration > Hardware/Additional
>   Drivers, the b43 drivers can be activated for use. A computer restart
>   may be required before using the wifi card.

It would be a good idea to remove the proprietary driver first:

```
sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source
```

Comment: before doing this do i need to remove previous drivers?

Comment: @SworoopMahapatra Yep, I updated my answer.

Comment: sudo apt-get remove bcmwl-kernel-source  i suppose..

Comment: @SworoopMahapatra Oops, sorry I'm a yum guy :)

Comment: :P figured so.
but still nothing.. restarted the system. not activated. Still showing the STA drivers. 
may be the drivers are blacklisted. how to remove?